# Refresh Button Box in Gtk GUI

Tags: c, submit, glade, gtk2

Is it possible to **refresh a button box** having a number of buttons, when a specific action is implemented such as Submit and Delete? On Submit a new button should be added and on Delete (after selecting the button), the button should get destroyed (not hiden). The GUI is designed using *Glade* in *Gtk-2* and codes are in the ***C** language*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. In the for loop instead of creating buttons from **i=0**, I did took a new *int* variable that holds the total number of buttons present already and now it only creates the new ones.

```
void Buttons()
{
    int i, totalrecord=0;
    int prevtotalbutton;
    for (i = prevtotalbutton ; i <totalrecord; i++)
    {
        ButtonfromArray = gtk_button_new_with_label (array);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(VBbox), ButtonfromArray, FALSE, TRUE, 1);
        gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (ButtonfromArray), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (ButtonsCreated), VBbox);
        gtk_widget_show (ButtonfromArray);
    } 
    prevtotalbutton=totalrecord;
}
```

Refreshing the button box is a bit more complicated here. This trick did work and without the use of any new functions to do *destroy* and all.

**Most of us face this problem. Wish my answer may help many like me.**

Answer (score 1):

Use `gtk_box_pack_start()` or `...pack_end()` or any of the other related methods to add a button to the box. Use `gtk_widget_destroy()` on a button to remove it from its container and destroy it at the same time.

Comment: I have created them with [gtk_box_pack_start()] in a loop. But I need to refresh the buttons box. How do [gtk_widget_destroy()] will destroy all present buttons and again create them with the new ones??? For single Submit its not a problem but when I add multiple buttons I face this problem and on deletetion of single button.

Comment: thnx for your time Sir neway.